# How can I add my picture to my public key using GnuPG?

Tags: public-key, gnupg

I've created a key pair using GnuPG. I've read that in addition to multiple identities and email addresses, one can also embed a small image (most usually of the user) to help perhaps with memory recall or to verify visually the identity of a person, say at key-signing parties etc.

How do I go about doing this with GnuPG 1.4.10 on Windows 7?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Run

```
  gpg --edit-key <your key id>
```

This will start gpg's key editing mode. Then use the command `addphoto`:

> gpg> addphoto
>
> Pick an image to use for your photo ID.  The image must be a JPEG
>   file. Remember that the image is stored within your public key.  If
>   you use a very large picture, your key will become very large as well!
>   Keeping the image close to 240x288 is a good size to use.
>
> Enter JPEG filename for photo ID: